# XML - Data At Root Level is Invalid

Tags: .net, xml, visual-studio, xsd, byte-order-mark

I have an XSD file that is encoded in UTF-8, and any text editor I run it through doesn't show any character at the beginning of the file, but when I pull it up in Visual Studio's debugger, I clearly see an empty box in front of the file.

[image: Box in file]

I also get the error:

**Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.**

[image]

Anyone know what this is?

Update: Edited post to qualify type of file. It's an XSD file created by Microsoft's XSD creator.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It turns out, the answer is that what I'm seeing is a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark), which is a character that tells whatever is loading the document what it is encoded in.  In my case, it's encoded in utf-8, so the corresponding BOM was `EF BB BF`, as shown below.  To remove it, I opened it up in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) and clicked on "Encode in UTF-8 without BOM", as shown below:

[image: Saving in NotePad++].

To actually see the BOM, I had to open it up in [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/) in Binary mode:, and conducted a [Google search for "`EF BB BF`"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=EF+BB+BF&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&oq=).

[image: binary mode]

It took me about 8 hours to find out this was what was causing it, so I thought I'd share this with everyone.

**Update**: If I had read Joel Spolsky's blog post: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), then I might not have had this problem.

Answer (score 29):

here's how you do it with vim:

```
# vim file.xml
:set nobomb
:wq
```