# Invalid character in the given encoding

Tags: c#, xmldocument

```
XmlDocument oXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

try
{
    oXmlDoc.Load(filePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Log Error Here
    try
    {
        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath, enc);
        String response = sr.ReadToEnd();
        oXmlDoc.LoadXml(response);
    }
    catch (Exception innerException)
    {
        // Log Error Here
        return false;
    }
}
```

I got xml file from third party which also include the Document Type Definition file after xml declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE SoccerMatchPlus SYSTEM "SoccerMatchPlus.dtd">
<SoccerMatchPlus matchid="33226">
<Booking id="13642055" time="47">
<Player id="370927">
<Name firstName="Lasse" initials="L" lastName="Nielsen">L Nielsen</Name>
</Player>
<Team id="26415" name="AæB" homeOrAway="Home"/>
</Booking>
</SoccerMatchPlus>
```

If I parse the file with Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 102, position 56. If I catch the exception and retry to parse the file then I got another issue, file parses but

I got the error Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\SoccerMatchPlus.dtd'.

Document Type Definition file named SoccerMatchPlus.dtd is added before the root element by third party.

In the case of Load method the parser loads the file from the location where xml file also exists.

I put the SoccerMatchPlus.dtd in other location where xml file resides, can I load that SoccerMatchPlus.dtd file from the specified location at runtime or can you tell me the better way to load the xml file which contains the invalid characters data?

Comment: It's not clear why you're trying to load a file which says it's in UTF-8 as if it were in ISO-8859-1.

Comment: because when I use ISO-8859-1 for oXmlDoc.LoadXml(response); which parses file successfully but can not find the location of SoccerMatchPlus.dtd file.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't got the file properly to start with. Did you cut and paste it into a text editor or something like that? I suspect the problem is that when you load it from a file, it's able to find the DTD relative to the file - so you should try to get the files right to start with.

Comment: When any invalid character is no t found then oXmlDoc.Load(filePath); works and don't show the message that [Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\SoccerMatchPlus.dtd']. If it throws exception then I try to work out with oXmlDoc.LoadXml(response); the method parses the file but also gives the above error. I download the XML files from FTP and can not manually edit the files. Is it possible to suppress the parser to find the DTD file from my given file path like (D:\XmlFiles\SoccerMatchPlus.dtd)?

Comment: If you downloaded the files from FTP, did you make sure you downloaded them in binary mode? If you load the file in an XML editor, what happens?

Comment: Yes I downloaded them in binary mode. Mostly file opens but some files which contains non ASCII characters, like Norwegian æ ø å , or French ê è é, shows the error [An invalid character was found in text content].

Comment: @JonSkeet let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1844/discussion-between-rais-hussain-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: No, as I'm popping in and out - I have many other things to do. Basically your XML file is corrupted - I suggest you contact the original source.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you after discuss with you I got many other things which I don't know before about the behavior of **Load** And **LoadXml** methods of **XmlDocument** class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `XmlResolver` property of `XmlDocument` class to disable DTD processing.

```
XmlDocument oXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
oXmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;
```

Comment: It worked, now I don't get the error [Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\SoccerMatchPlus.dtd']. XML file is parsing correctly.

Comment: @Rais: But this isn't really fixing the issue of the file you've got being invalid to start with. I would concentrate on fixing that underlying problem.

Comment: @Rais you should also try to strip the illegal characters, before calling `Load`

Comment: @Adeel If I strip the illegal character which can be first name of player then it would give wrong meaning. For instance player's complete name is [Moström Mattias], if I would replace it with [Mostrm Mattias] it would give wrong meaning.