# Error in loading xml file in XmlDocument

Tags: c#

Hi I have below xml file that I am trying to load in xml document using below code -

```
XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.LoadXml(@"C:\MappingFiles\InputFile.xml");
```

but its throwing error - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Xml file is fully structured still its throwing error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CAS xmlns="http://www.test.com/schema/CASXmlSchema">
  <OperationList>
    <Operation id="1">
      <Type>calculate</Type>
      <calculateParams>
        <RequestInfo>
          <CalcRequestTradeParam>
            <TempTradeList>
              <Trades>
                <TemplateDefinitionID>TRADE.EQ.EQEUROPEAN</TemplateDefinitionID>
                <TradeParameters>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Trade ID</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>String</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>EU1</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Template</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>String</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>TRADE.EQ.EQEUROPEAN</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Currency</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>String</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>USD</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Final Fixing Date</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>Date</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>15-Apr-14</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Ticker</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>String</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>C</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Flavor</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>String</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>Put</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Position</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>String</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>Sell</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Number of shares</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>Double</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>5</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                  <StringToParameterValueEntry>
                    <StringToParameterValueKey>Strike</StringToParameterValueKey>
                    <StringToParameterValueValue>
                      <ParameterType>Double</ParameterType>
                      <NonTabularValue>40</NonTabularValue>
                      <TableValue/>
                    </StringToParameterValueValue>
                  </StringToParameterValueEntry>
                </TradeParameters>
              </Trades>
            </TempTradeList>
          </CalcRequestTradeParam>
          <CalcRequestMarketParam>
            <Expression>Id >= 0</Expression>
          </CalcRequestMarketParam>
          <CalculateRequestOutputs>PV</CalculateRequestOutputs>
          <Currency>USD</Currency>
          <TaskName>XML Request Test</TaskName>
          <JobCount>10</JobCount>
          <CalculationMethod>OnceAndHold</CalculationMethod>
          <TimeFactorSeconds>0</TimeFactorSeconds>
          <ProcessorName/>
          <ProcessorOptions/>
        </RequestInfo>
        <ResultInfo>
          <TaskId>0</TaskId>
          <TradeStartIndex>0</TradeStartIndex>
          <TradeNum>15</TradeNum>
          <MarketStartIndex>0</MarketStartIndex>
          <MarketNum>1</MarketNum>         
          <ResultRequestOutputs>Template</ResultRequestOutputs>
          <ResultRequestOutputs>Currency</ResultRequestOutputs>
          <ResultRequestOutputs>PV</ResultRequestOutputs>
          <RequestType>Individual</RequestType>
          <GroupSelection/>
        </ResultInfo>
        <RequestTimeoutMilliseconds>60000</RequestTimeoutMilliseconds>
      </calculateParams>
    </Operation>
  </OperationList>
</CAS>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: for a start, use `XDocument` not `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Does your document have the blank spaces before "<?xml ..." ? If so, try remove them

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400895/strange-behavior-when-loading-xml-via-xmldocument/60158069#60158069

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calling the wrong method, see [this question and answer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load.aspx)

You should be calling `XmlDocument.Load`.

---

In fact, you'd be better off doing

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path");
```

and using [linq to xml.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660676/xmldocument-load-vs-xmldocument-loadxml)

Answer (score 1):

Use XMLDocument.Load(). This accepts an xml file

whereas XMLDocument.LoadXml() accepts an xml string.

Comment: I had the same error as the OP. I was trying to load a file using `XMLDocument.Load()`. It wouldn't work. So I read in the file as a string: `string allText = File.ReadAllText(myFilePath);`, then did `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); doc.LoadXml(allText);` - it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to read it in as a string and don't want to do `XMLDocument.Load()` as others have suggested, you can do `XMLDocument.LoadXml()`, but it should be as a string, first:

```
string myFilePath = @"C:\MappingFiles\InputFile.xml";
string allText = File.ReadAllText(myFilePath);

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(allText);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

I found that this can work even when `.Load()` on the file, itself, does not.