# Strange behavior when loading xml via XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I am receiving an error regarding improper format when loading an xml document in c#. When using the following code,

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(fileName);
```

I receive the error afterwards:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

However, if I change the first occurrence to the following, everything works as expected and the type of xmlDoc is in fact XmlDocument:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(fileName);
```

A snippet of my xml is file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutomatedTests type="asdf">
    <TestGroup>
    </TestGroup>
</AutomatedTests>
```

Is there any explanation as to why this could be happening?

Comment: Is your xml really missing a closing ">", or did you just mis-copy?:)

Comment: Ah good catch. I miscopied!

Comment: [XmlDocument.LoadXml Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx) - Loads the XML document from the specified string. while [XmlDocument.Load Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx) -
Loads the specified XML data from a Stream, a URL, a TextReader, or an XmlReader.

Comment: @StuartLC this isn't a duplicate question. The question that you linked refers to XmlDocument.Load, not XmlDocument.LoadXml, they're two separate unique functions. Additionally, this was just a typo. If you're going to close it, close it for not being a good question.

Comment: @Hondros looks like a Dupe. OP on the linked question tried to do `Doc.LoadXml(@"C:\MappingFiles\InputFile.xml");`, and you're trying to do `xmlDoc.LoadXml(fileName);`? The fix in both instances is simple - use `Load` for files, streams etc, and `LoadXml` is to be used only if you already have the xml in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming filename is the path, try the below code.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
```

XmlDocument.Load loads XML either from a stream, TextReader, path/URL, or XmlReader and XmlDocument.LoadXml loads the XML contained within a string.

Comment: This is the exact code that I have in the first snippet above. It returns the error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."

Comment: @Hondros you have `LoadXml` in both snippets

Comment: I can't believe I missed that. Coincidentally, that's the same call that I use in a different function a few lines above that in my code. Thanks for that catch, everything is running properly now!

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to read it in as a string and don't want to do `XMLDocument.Load()` as another suggested, you can do `XMLDocument.LoadXml()`, but it should be as a string, first:

```
string myFilePath = @"C:\MappingFiles\InputFile.xml";
string allText = File.ReadAllText(myFilePath);

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(allText);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

I found that this can work even when `.Load()` on the file, itself, does not.