# Read XML with VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm struggling with reading my XML in VB and getting the data I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <Install>
        <Package>
            <Name>Office2010</Name>
            <Path>C:\Windows\Office</Path>
            <Default>0</Default>
        </Package>
        <Package>
            <Name>CCleaner</Name>
            <Path>C:\Windows\Cleaner</Path>
            <Default>0</Default>
        </Package>
    </Install>
```

I'm trying to read a whole node at a time, so I can fetch all the values of it.

```
package.Name
package.Path
package.Default
```

Is this possible? I'm struggling with this for over 2 hours now. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple `For Each` loop and XML literals, like:

```
' or load the XML with XDocument.Load(...) '
Dim xml = <Install>
            <Package>
                <Name>Office2010</Name>
                <Path>C:\Windows\Office</Path>
                <Default>0</Default>
            </Package>
            <Package>
                <Name>CCleaner</Name>
                <Path>C:\Windows\Cleaner</Path>
                <Default>0</Default>
            </Package>
        </Install>

' If you used XDocument.Load(...), use xml.Root.<Package> instead '
For Each package In xml.<Package>
    Console.WriteLine(package.<Name>.Value)
    Console.WriteLine(package.<Path>.Value)
    Console.WriteLine(package.<Default>.Value)
Next
```

Comment: I Really can't get this to work. Your example is working as expected, but when I try to read my XML file, I get an error or it thinks that my .xml is empty.

Can somebody provide me with a quick snippet of XDocument.Load()? I Think I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: If you use `XDocument.Load(yourpath)` to load the XML, use `xml.Root.<Package>` instead of `xml.<Package>`

Answer (score 1):

```
// parse your XML into an XDocument
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
// get "Install" element
Dim install As XElement = doc.Root

// iterate over "Package" elements in install
For Each package As XElement In install.Elements("Package")
    Dim name As String = package.Element("Name").Value
    Dim path As String = package.Element("Path").Value
    Dim def As String = package.Element("Default").Value
Next
```

Comment: Hi Saeb, i'm getting: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. I'm being stupid?

Comment: @Jente, post your complete XML.

Comment: Actually thatis the complete XML, except the version. I've added that to my post.

Comment: @Jente, Nothing wrong with the declaration, so it has to be a problem with how the XML file is being generated/written. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24513288/68080).

Comment: Hmm, tried it, but no luck. I even created a new XML (I've created it in notepad), same error.

Comment: @Jente, can you upload the problematic file somewhere?

Comment: @Jente Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62277/discussion-between-saeb-amini-and-jente).