# How to read the WSDL of a WCF service from a URL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

I'm trying to read a WSDL from a URL to dynamically generate the proxy for the WCF service.
This is my code:

```
XmlTextReader xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(description)) 
if (ServiceDescription.CanRead(xmlTextReader))
{
    ...
}
```

I get an `XmlException` from method `ServiceDescription.CanRead`.
The error massage is "*Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1*".

Browsing the WDSL URL in IE, I can see the following tag at the start before tag `<wsdl:definitions ...> ... </wsdl:definitions>` which doesn't appear in chrome.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Could that be the issue? but I suppose `ServiceDescription.CanRead` should be able to recognise that. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What about inspecting the XML that's being read? `CanRead` is just calling `CanDeserialize` on an inner instance of XmlSerializer and returning that value.

Comment: And the xml declaration you're seeing in IE is optional but valid. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007427/does-a-valid-xml-file-require-an-xml-declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007427/does-a-valid-xml-file-require-an-xml-declaration)

Comment: This could be it - an extra hidden character that prevents parsing of the XML. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947238/why-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1-for-xml-document/24513288](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947238/why-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1-for-xml-document/24513288)

Comment: Try pasting the code from my answer above the first line of code in your post. I don't know if it's the fix in this case but maybe it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this before the first line included in your question:

```
var byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
if (description.StartsWith(byteOrderMarkUtf8))
{
    var lastIndexOfUtf8 = byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length - 1;
    description = description.Remove(0, lastIndexOfUtf8);
}
```

Borrowed from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947238/why-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1-for-xml-document/24513288).

Comment: I initially deleted this because it's mostly copy and paste from someone else's answer to another question with trivial edits. I'm going to delete it again after OP gets a chance to try it.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that was the issue. fixed now!