# EF Core : How can I Create Geometry by Parsing Spatial Data

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, nettopologysuite

I had a requirement of storing static spatial data with some polygons, I imported GeoJson into my SQL Server to massage secondary data, once I had the correct data I exported my data into a Json (using `FOR JSON PATH`).

Now since geometry is a CLR type, I needed to convert it to string to allow export to JSON.

```
SELECT 
    Id, Bounds.ToString() as Bounds 
FROM
    ...
FOR JSON PATH
```

Now this produced a JSON file to the effect of

```
  [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Bounds": "POLYGON ((93.044663537224707 23.410524583651519, ...
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Bounds": "MULTIPOLYGON (((93.046192725017278 23.666228900665988...
  },
```

I need to use this for seeding initial static data, which will be loaded from  but I do not know how to convert string Geometry to NetTopology Geometry.

Where did I go or and what am I missing? Is there a better way for me to seed this data? Or is there a way to parse the text I have in EF Core to populate the geometry?

Comment: My lengthy answer (below) became irrelevant with WKTReader.

Answer (score 1):

I have found an answer by researching further and I am also done with testing so thought I would share with anyone in similar boat.

The way to parse string to Geometry is by using [GMLReader](https://github.com/synhershko/nettopologysuite/blob/master/NetTopologySuite/IO/GML2/GMLReader.cs)

But for that we to Generate Gml instead of string

```
SELECT 
Id, Bounds.AsGml() as Bounds 
FROM
    ...
```

This produces Xml on SQL Server

```
  <Bounds>
    <Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
      <exterior>
        <LinearRing>
          <posList>93.044663537224707 23.410524583651519 92.9467955185...
```

But this only solves half of my problem, I needed to generate JSON and use that JSON in seeding, but if I were flexible in using XML instead I could have exported by seed data with XML

```
SELECT 
  [Id],
  [Bounds].AsGml() as Bounds
  ...
FROM ...
FOR XML PATH
```

Would have produced an XML with the data like..

```
<row>
  <Id>1</Id>
  <Bounds>
    <Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
      <exterior>
        <LinearRing>
          <posList>93.044663537224707 23.410524583651519 92.9467955185...
```

So I decided to encode the generated GML to Base64 to generate JSON, this Base64 would be decoded while parsing the geometry for seeding.

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Geometry_Encode_Gml_Base64]
    (
        @value geometry
    )
    RETURNS varchar(max)
    AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @source varbinary(max) = convert(varbinary(max), @value.AsGml())
        RETURN cast(N'' as xml).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:variable("@source"))', 'varchar(max)')
    END
```

And generated JSON by executing the query

```
SELECT 
  [Id],
  dbo.Geometry_Encode_Gml_Base64([Bounds]) as Bounds
  ...
FROM ...
FOR JSON PATH
```

Which produces JSON like,

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Bounds": "\/\/48AFAAbwBsAHkAZwBvAG4AIAB4AG0AbABuAHMAPQAiAGgAdAB0AH..."
}, ...
```

Now while reading and seeding I can simply, decode the Base64 string and read it with GMLReader

```
GMLReader gmlReader = new GMLReader(NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(srid: 4326));

Geometry bounds = gmlReader.Read(DecodeBase64(jsonRow.Bounds))
```

NOTE : DecodeBase64 should  use the encoding (Unicode/Utf8 etc) that your database uses to decode

WARNING : I encountered problem with loading the extracted GML with GMLReader after decoding because there was a problem with some illegal bytes that were added (SQL Server?) if you find the same problem see how to resolve if you have [XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947238/why-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1-for-xml-document/24513288#24513288)