# Xamarin Forms - Epub: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred

Tags: xamarin.forms, stream, epub

I am converting my epub file URL to stream and saving to local DB as bytes like below:

```
Stream stream;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = await client.GetAsync(fileUrl);
stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
epubBook = EpubReader.ReadBook(stream);

//saving to folder
byte[] bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUrl);
var folderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, filename);
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
```

This is working fine for most of the files. But some file URLs showing `System.AggregateException`.

**Exception Details**

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Version number '1.1' is invalid. Line 1, position 16.) ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Version number '1.1' is invalid. Line 1, position 16.
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.Exception e) [0x00027] in <0757e7484a1349cca3b4558c721885b2>:0
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.String res, System.String arg) [0x00029] in <0757e7484a1349cca3b4558c721885b2>:0
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration (System.Boolean isTextDecl) [0x0061f] in <0757e7484a1349cca3b4558c721885b2>:0
> at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read () [0x000c6] in <0757e7484a1349cca3b4558c721885b2>:0
> at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, System.Xml.Linq.LoadOptions options) [0x00016] in <89374192b20a41739cf7c5bb822846fe>:0
> at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Xml.Linq.LoadOptions options) [0x0000f] in <89374192b20a41739cf7c5bb822846fe>:0
> at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in <89374192b20a41739cf7c5bb822846fe>:0
> at VersOne.Epub.Internal.XmlUtils+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.b__0 () [0x00000] in <7c46dbfe3ebf403389304a938822832e>:0
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0
> at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in <46c2fa109b574c7ea6739f9fe2350976>:0
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Sample file URLs having this issue:

https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/catholic-brain/prod/dc/cbrain-app/files/doc-lib/2020/08/10/12/56/42/068/head/9781612781495_EPUB.epub

https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/catholic-brain/prod/dc/cbrain-app/files/doc-lib/2020/08/10/07/36/06/376/head/9781612781358_EPUB.epub

I am using [EpubReader.Cross](https://github.com/g0rdan/EpubReader.Cross) Nuget for parsing the epub file.

I have uploaded a sample [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16nyh9zQTnNDcrnGLaEyob0RDjCryJ73S/view?usp=sharing) for the easy reference.

Comment: Check  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343227/system-xml-xmlexception-in-c-sharp

Comment: "System.Xml.XmlException: Version number '1.1' is invalid" - it sounds like some of your files have invalid XML in them

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I didn't see any useful point on the shared thread

Comment: @Jason How I can solve it?

Comment: catch the exception and display an error message?  It really depends on what your requirements say about handling corrupt data

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT and Jason I have added a sample project link on the question, could you please have a look?

Comment: I ran your epub through a validation tool and it reports **110 errors**.  Your data is bad.

Comment: @Jason Which validation tool?

Comment: https://www.ebookit.com/tools/bp/Bo/eBookIt/epub-validator

Comment: @Jason I have tried a working epub file, that also shows error

Comment: apparently the library you have chosen handles some errors and does not handle others.  If you have questions I suggest you open an issue with the author.  Or fork the source and modify it to behave the way you want.