# Makefile.win:1: ***missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know this error relates to missing TAB, but I somehow cannot find out where on line 1 is the tab missing:

Makefile:

```
## -*- mode: make; tab-width: 8; -*-
##
## Simple Makefile
##
## TODO: 
##  proper configure for non-Debian file locations,   [ Done ]
##  allow RHOME to be set for non-default R etc

## comment this out if you need a different version of R, 
## and set set R_HOME accordingly as an environment variable

R_HOME =        $(shell R RHOME)

sources =       $(wildcard *.cpp)
programs =      $(sources:.cpp=)


## include headers and libraries for R 
RCPPFLAGS =         $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --cppflags)
RLDFLAGS =      $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config --ldflags)
RBLAS =         $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config BLAS_LIBS)
RLAPACK =       $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config LAPACK_LIBS)

## if you need to set an rpath to R itself, also uncomment
#RRPATH :=      -Wl,-rpath,$(R_HOME)/lib

## include headers and libraries for Rcpp interface classes
RCPPINCL =      $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RCPPLIBS =      $(shell echo 'Rcpp:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)


## include headers and libraries for RInside embedding classes
RINSIDEINCL =       $(shell echo 'RInside:::CxxFlags()' | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)
RINSIDELIBS =       $(shell echo 'RInside:::LdFlags()'  | $(R_HOME)/bin/R --vanilla --slave)

## compiler etc settings used in default make rules
CXX =           $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CXX)
CPPFLAGS =      -Wall $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD config CPPFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS =      $(RCPPFLAGS) $(RCPPINCL) $(RINSIDEINCL) $(shell $(R_HOME)/bin/R CMD 

config CXXFLAGS)
LDLIBS =        $(RLDFLAGS) $(RRPATH) $(RBLAS) $(RLAPACK) $(RCPPLIBS) $(RINSIDELIBS)

all: $(programs)
    @test -x /usr/bin/strip && strip $^

run: $(programs)
    @for p in $(programs); do echo; echo "Running $$p:"; ./$$p; done

clean:
    rm -vf $(programs)
    rm -vrf *.dSYM

runAll:
    for p in $(programs); do echo "Running $$p"; ./$$p; done
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. I suggest try to minimize the example-- remove lines and test, until you find the smallest, simplest makefile that gives this error. It might also be useful to tell us which version of Make you are using (`make -v`).

Comment: This is almost always the same problem: your recipes (the shell commands) *must start with a TAB character*. You appear to be using spaces instead.

Comment: @reinierpost, doesn't the error message indicate a problem on line 1? Or is this one of those charming eccentricities of Microsoft?

Comment: It is *not* an eccentricity of Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I have faced the same problem with a Makefile saved by some editor on Windows. The cause then was a [BOM (Byte Order Mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the Makefile which was confusing Make.

To check if it is so you could (*manually*) copy and paste the whole Makefile (or maybe except for the header comment) into a new file created in some other editor/IDE. Also here is [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/291462/545027) on how to remove BOM on Windows.

Comment: Eldar, and @Beta : Please read my comments on both the answers below. Thanks for being helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If your "Makefile.win" is an exact copy, then replace all spaces before the commands with tabs:

> all: $(programs)
>   <**insert tab here, no spaces**>@test -x /usr/bin/strip && strip $^
>
> run: $(programs)
>   <**insert tab here, no spaces**>@for p in $(programs); do echo; echo "Running $$p:"; ./$$p; done
>
> clean:
>   <**insert tab here, no spaces**>rm -vf $(programs)
>   <**insert tab here, no spaces**>rm -vrf *.dSYM
>
> runAll:
>   <**insert tab here, no spaces**>for p in $(programs); do echo "Running $$p"; ./$$p; done

Comment: I "had" done that "before" posting the question here. But I don't know how this Notepad treats the tab! When I copied the makefile to Linux and opened it through Kwrite, I realized that I "again" have to replace those tabs with new tabs!

Answer (score 1):

The line just before `LDLIBS` apparently reads:

```
config CXXFLAGS)
```

That would generate a makefile syntax error, but I would expect it to be with a line number larger than 1.

Comment: Thankful to you. It was the fault of "damn" `Notepad` of Windows! the damn thing was showing the error on line 1. I copied the makefile to Linux and opened it through Kwrite. Then the compiler showed the error on the "proper" line number.