# Invalid descriptor Exception - UIMA with JSF and Tomcat 7

Tags: xml, jsf-2, uima

I am getting an exception running a UIMA application on TOMCAT 7.0.

**STEPS**

1) Created a dynamic web project

2) Added *"ADD UIMA NATURE"*

3) Created primitive analysis engine (AE). Each primitive AE has an annotation type and an annotator (took example from [here](http://sujitpal.blogspot.in/2011/03/smart-query-parsing-with-uima.html))

**Snippet from the link**

**ZipCode.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <typeSystemDescription xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
      <name>ZipCode</name>
      <description>Defines the zipcode type</description>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <vendor>MyCompany, Inc.</vendor>
      <types>
        <typeDescription>
          <name>com.mycompany.myapp.uima.annotators.zipcode.ZipCodeAnnotation</name>
          <description>ZipCode</description>
          <supertypeName>uima.tcas.Annotation</supertypeName>
        </typeDescription>
      </types>
    </typeSystemDescription>
```

**ZipCodeAE.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
   <analysisEngineDescription xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
      <frameworkImplementation>org.apache.uima.java</frameworkImplementation>
      <primitive>true</primitive>
      <annotatorImplementationName>
        com.mycompany.myapp.uima.annotators.zipcode.ZipCodeAnnotator
      </annotatorImplementationName>
      <analysisEngineMetaData>
        <name>Zip Code Annotator</name>
        <description>Recognize and annotate zip code in text</description>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <vendor>MyCompany, Inc.</vendor>
        <configurationParameters></configurationParameters>
        <configurationParameterSettings></configurationParameterSettings>
        <typeSystemDescription>
          <imports>
            <import location="ZipCode.xml"/>
          </imports>
        </typeSystemDescription>
        <typePriorities></typePriorities>
        <fsIndexCollection></fsIndexCollection>
        <capabilities>
          <capability>
            <inputs></inputs>
            <outputs>
              <type>com.mycompany.myapp.uima.annotators.zipcode.ZipCode</type>
            </outputs>
            <languagesSupported></languagesSupported>
          </capability>
        </capabilities>
        <operationalProperties>
          <modifiesCas>true</modifiesCas>
          <multipleDeploymentAllowed>true</multipleDeploymentAllowed>
          <outputsNewCASes>false</outputsNewCASes>
        </operationalProperties>
      </analysisEngineMetaData>
      <externalResourceDependencies></externalResourceDependencies>
      <resourceManagerConfiguration></resourceManagerConfiguration>
    </analysisEngineDescription>
```

**ZipCodeAnnotator.java**

```
public class ZipCodeAnnotator extends JCasAnnotator_ImplBase {

      private Pattern zipCodePattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{5}(-\\d{4})*");

      @Override
      public void process(JCas jCAS) throws AnalysisEngineProcessException {
        String text = jCAS.getDocumentText();
        Matcher matcher = zipCodePattern.matcher(text);
        int pos = 0;
        while (matcher.find(pos)) {
          ZipCodeAnnotation annotation = new ZipCodeAnnotation(jCAS);
          annotation.setBegin(matcher.start());
          annotation.setEnd(matcher.end());
          annotation.addToIndexes();
          pos = matcher.end();
        }
      }
    }
```

**TestCase**

```
public class AddressAnnotatorTest {

  private final String[] TEST_STRINGS = new String[] {
    "Dr Goldwater, University of Michigan, Ann Arbor, MI 01234",
    "Microsoft, 1 Microsoft Way, Redmond, WA",
    "Apple, 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014",
    "IBM, 1 New Orchard Road, Armonk, NY 10504",
    "Google, 1600 Amphitheater Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043",
    "Healthline, 600 3rd Street, San Francisco, CA 94107",
    "Jane Doe, Lake Tahoe, California",
    "Miss Liberty, Empire State Building, New York, NY"
  };

  @Test
  public void testAddressAE() throws Exception {
    AnalysisEngine ae = TestUtils.getAE(
      "src/main/java/com/mycompany/myapp/uima/annotators/aggregates/AddressAE.xml", 
      null);
    for (String text : TEST_STRINGS) {
      JCas jcas = TestUtils.runAE(ae, text);
      TestUtils.printResults(jcas);
    }
  }
}
```

If I test this application through JUnit test case (as given in the code above), it is running successfully without any exception, but when I run this application on Tomcat by creating a simple xhtml page with a button. and On click on the button, it's throwing an exception.

**Here's the code snippet**

**XHTML**

```
 <p:commandButton id="create" value="Print Result"
    actionListener="#{demoClass.testZipAE}" ajax="true">
    </p:commandButton>
```

**DemoClass.java**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "demoClass")
@SessionScoped()
public class DemoClass implements Serializable {

public AnalysisEngine getAE(
              String descriptor, Map<String,Object> params) 
              throws IOException, InvalidXMLException, 
              ResourceInitializationException {
            AnalysisEngine ae = null;
            try {

              XMLInputSource in = new XMLInputSource(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(descriptor), null);
              AnalysisEngineDescription desc = 
                UIMAFramework.getXMLParser().
                parseAnalysisEngineDescription(in);
              if (params != null) {
                for (String key : params.keySet()) {
                  desc.getAnalysisEngineMetaData().
                  getConfigurationParameterSettings().
                  setParameterValue(key, params.get(key));
                }
              }
              ae = UIMAFramework.produceAnalysisEngine(desc);
            } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new ResourceInitializationException(e);
            }
            return ae;
          }

          public JCas runAE(AnalysisEngine ae, String text)
              throws AnalysisEngineProcessException, 
              ResourceInitializationException {
            JCas jcas = ae.newJCas();
            jcas.setDocumentText(text);
            ProcessTrace trace = ae.process(jcas);
            for (ProcessTraceEvent evt : trace.getEvents()) {
              if (evt != null && evt.getResultMessage() != null &&
                  evt.getResultMessage().contains("error")) {
                throw new AnalysisEngineProcessException(
                  new Exception(evt.getResultMessage()));
              }
            }
            return jcas;
          }

          public void printResults(JCas jcas) {
            FSIndex index = jcas.getAnnotationIndex();
            for (Iterator<Annotation> it = index.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
              Annotation annotation = it.next();
              List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();
              if (annotation.getType().getName().contains("com.mycompany")) {
                features = annotation.getType().getFeatures();
              }
              List<String> fasl = new ArrayList<String>();
              for (Feature feature : features) {
                if (feature.getName().contains("com.mycompany")) {
                  String name = feature.getShortName();
                  String value = annotation.getStringValue(feature);
                  fasl.add(name + "=\"" + value + "\"");
                }
              }
              System.out.println(
                annotation.getType().getShortName() + ": " +
                annotation.getCoveredText() + " " +
                (fasl.size() > 0 ? StringUtils.join(fasl.iterator(), ",") : "") + " " +
                annotation.getBegin() + ":" + annotation.getEnd());
            }
            System.out.println("==");
          }

          public void testZipAE(ActionEvent event) throws AnalysisEngineProcessException, ResourceInitializationException {
            AnalysisEngine ae;
            try {
                ae = getAE(
                  "TestAE.xml", 
                  null);
                 for (String text : TEST_STRINGS) {
                      JCas jcas = runAE(ae, text);
                      printResults(jcas);
                    }
            } catch (InvalidXMLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ResourceInitializationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
```

**TestAE.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<analysisEngineDescription xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
  <frameworkImplementation>org.apache.uima.java</frameworkImplementation>
  <primitive>false</primitive>
  <delegateAnalysisEngineSpecifiers>
    <delegateAnalysisEngine key="ZipCodeAE">
      <import location="ZipCodeAE.xml"/>
    </delegateAnalysisEngine>
  </delegateAnalysisEngineSpecifiers>
  <analysisEngineMetaData>
    <name>TestAE</name>
    <description>Runs the delegate AEs together</description>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <configurationParameters searchStrategy="language_fallback"/>
    <configurationParameterSettings/>
    <flowConstraints>
      <fixedFlow>
        <node>ZipCodeAE</node>
      </fixedFlow>
    </flowConstraints>
    <typePriorities/>
    <fsIndexCollection/>
    <capabilities>
      <capability>
        <inputs/>
        <outputs/>
        <languagesSupported/>
      </capability>
    </capabilities>
    <operationalProperties>
      <modifiesCas>true</modifiesCas>
      <multipleDeploymentAllowed>true</multipleDeploymentAllowed>
      <outputsNewCASes>false</outputsNewCASes>
    </operationalProperties>
  </analysisEngineMetaData>
  <resourceManagerConfiguration/>
</analysisEngineDescription>
```

**Exception**

```
 org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException: Invalid descriptor at <unknown source>.
        at com.acn.hps.alpes.gi.cip.jsf.AnalyzeFile.getAE(AnalyzeFile.java:208)
        at com.acn.hps.alpes.gi.cip.jsf.AnalyzeFile.testAddressAE(AnalyzeFile.java:145)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:101)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:77)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.apache.uima.util.InvalidXMLException: Invalid descriptor at <unknown source>.
        at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parse(XMLParser_impl.java:194)
        at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parseAnalysisEngineDescription(XMLParser_impl.java:492)
        at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parseAnalysisEngineDescription(XMLParser_impl.java:473)
        at com.acn.hps.alpes.gi.cip.jsf.AnalyzeFile.getAE(AnalyzeFile.java:198)
        ... 36 more
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.uima.util.impl.XMLParser_impl.parse(XMLParser_impl.java:177)
        ... 39 more
```

I initially thought, the exception is being thrown out of because of any invalid character in XML, then following this link ([XML - Data At Root Level is Invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291455/xml-data-at-root-level-is-invalid)) and made sure the xml is encoded without BOM (Byte Order Mark). Unfortunately this didn't help.

Any Idea how to get rid of this exception.

Comment: maybe an encoding problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>` usually has to be the very first thing in an XML file. No spaces, no extra lines before it. Looks like the `ZipCodeAE.xml` might not be following that requirement.

Otherwise, using the debugger to discover in which file the problem really occurred, would certainly be helpful.