# "Data at the root level is invalid" error when adding ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, resourcedictionary

While attempting to load a MS standard resource dictionary, "Luna.Metallic.xaml", the following error is thrown during compile:

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. XML is not valid.

I tried both the Notepad++ as well as vim solutions to no avail.

What am I doing wrong?

Many Thanks!

```
<Application x:Class="test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!-- Resources scoped at the Application level should be defined here. -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Luna.Metallic.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

=> Here is a VIM hex display of "Luna.Metallic.xaml", showing no non-displayable characters

```
0000000: 3c21 2d2d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d  <!--============
0000010: 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d  ================
0000020: 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d  ================
0000030: 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d  ================
0000040: 3d3d 3d3d 3d0d 0a43 6f70 7972 6967 6874  =====..Copyright
0000050: 2028 4329 204d 6963 726f 736f 6674 2043   (C) Microsoft C
0000060: 6f72 706f 7261 7469 6f6e 2e20 2041 6c6c  orporation.  All
0000070: 2072 6967 6874 7320 7265 7365 7276 6564   rights reserved
0000080: 2e0d 0a0d 0a54 6865 6d65 2053 7479 6c65  .....Theme Style
0000090: 7320 466f 7220 5769 6e64 6f77 7320 5072  s For Windows Pr
00000a0: 6573 656e 7461 7469 6f6e 2046 6f75 6e64  esentation Found
00000b0: 6174 696f 6e20 5665 7273 696f 6e20 0300  ation Version ..
00000c0: 0000 200d 0a3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d  .. ..===========
00000d0: 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d  ================
00000e0: 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d  ================
00000f0: 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d  ================
0000100: 3d3d 3d3d 3d3d 3d2d 2d3e 0d0a 0d0a 3c52  =======-->....<R
0000110: 6573 6f75 7263 6544 6963 7469 6f6e 6172  esourceDictionar
0000120: 7920 786d 6c6e 733d 2268 7474 703a 2f2f  y xmlns="http://
0000130: 7363 6865 6d61 732e 6d69 6372 6f73 6f66  schemas.microsof
0000140: 742e 636f 6d2f 7769 6e66 782f 3230 3036  t.com/winfx/2006
0000150: 2f78 616d 6c2f 7072 6573 656e 7461 7469  /xaml/presentati
0000160: 6f6e 220d 0a20 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020  on"..
```

Comment: Have you followed the directions outlined here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291455/xml-data-at-root-level-is-invalid

Comment: Since the file came from MS, I assumed it was clean. I tried both the Notepad++, as well as vim, but same problem.

Comment: if you follow the instructions laid out in that answer and open it in TextPad in binary mode, what do you see at the beginning of the file? (Include a screenshot much like I did in my question; that'll help us determine what is there, if it's not a UTF-8 BOM).

Comment: I am not yet able to attach an image. I've copied the text from VIM hex mode.