# SolrNET - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I am using [Solar](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/): 7.0.1 on: localhost:8983/solr/global

I am using [SolrNET](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet) 0.8.1 with the following code example:

```
using SolrNet;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

Startup.Init<SOLRModel>("http://localhost:8983/solr/global");
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SOLRModel>>();
var results = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("*:*&wt=xml")); // Throws Error Here.
```

I am getting an error:

```
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
```

I am using default schema, have also tried the techproducts example, get the same error.

I can navigate to: http://localhost:8983/solr/global/select?q=*:* and I get the normal JSON Response.

Using the `&wt=xml` gives me well formatted XML Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <response>
    - <lst name="responseHeader">
           <int name="status">0</int> 
          <int name="QTime">0</int> 
    - <lst name="params">
        <str name="q">*:*</str> 
        <str name="wt">xml</str> 
    </lst>
    </lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0" /> 
</response>
```

Please can someone tell me where I might look to solve this error.

Comment: Are you sure SolrNET supports the XML output? Sounds like it might expect the JSON output?

Comment: Yes, XDocument, XElement and so on. See: https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Impl/ISolrResponseParser.cs as an example. Weather I use '&wt=xml' or not, the error is present.

Comment: Do you get anything useful in the Solr log? And you probably meant `*:*` as the query, not `*.*`. I'm not sure you should include `global` in your URL - according to the SolrNet docs it seems that is provided by the model / the model name? That would give a 404, which would result in a parse error when attempting to parse the returned 404 HTML as XML.

Comment: global is the core name, random name, I had techproducts before, gives the same error. without the core name I get 404 not found. Logs are logging errors as I make them, but nothing against the query, only if I make a mistake.

Comment: I've been having the same issue. The logs show that it is having the following problem:  Error adding field 'end'='2017-08-05'

Comment: @John Ten Cate - Thanks for sharing. I do not get an error. My logs are error free for this particular issue, so I think my XML is being returned successfully. SolrNET is creating an XML byte-order mark (BOM) Error `?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` where there should not be a preceding `?`  http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-byte-order-mark - The solution for me was to Write my Own SolrNET.

Comment: To add, this problem appears to be created because the way the data is handled. Encoding: UTF-8 without signature. Simply, the difference between XmlDocument.LoadXml("Path") and XmlDocument.Load("Path") can change this situation.

Comment: Best links I have found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291455/xml-data-at-root-level-is-invalid and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1/32713239#32713239 - Special thanks to those posters, they are vary helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SolrNet [doc page](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Querying.md) says this:

> Whatever you give it is passed straight to Solr's q parameter

The `&wt=xml` should not be passed to the `q` parameter, SolrNet needs to treat this as a separate parameter entirely. This goes for any additional parameters you want to set such as start, sort, etc.

The correct way is to use the overload `solr.Query(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions options)` and pass these parameters through the `ExtraParams` property.

A complete example:

```
using SolrNet;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

Startup.Init<SOLRModel>("http://localhost:8983/solr/global");
var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<SOLRModel>>();

var options = new QueryOptions();

options.ExtraParams = new KeyValuePair<string,string>[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("wt", "xml")
};

var results = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("*:*"), options);
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out that by default solrnet returns json. To fix the issue I passed in extraparams for queryoptions on the query for setting 'wt' to xml. See the documentation for setting extra params.

Comment: John, this I already covered several times in my Question. This is not the answer to my question.